# Laravel eager load relationship with condition based on the parent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I've this query to list all the *users* with their corresponding relationships.

*user* has many *tasks*
each *tasks* has many *worktimes* and these *worktimes* can have different *users*

ie, each task can be shared by different users, hence they have individual worktime for each task.

i've tried the below code

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.contract_type')
    ->with([
        'tasks' => function($query) use ($from, $to){
            $query->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])
                ->select('tasks.id', 'tasks.date');
        },
        'tasks.worktimes' => function($query) {
            //$query->where('user_id', ?)
            $query->withCount([
                    'tags as late_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 1);
                    },
                    'tags as early_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 2);
                    },
                    'tags as others_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 3);
                    }
                ]
            );
        }
     ])
     ->get();
```

here the relationship *tasks.worktimes* also fetching the worktime of other users (which is kind of expected), but I want to limit this to fetch only the parent user's worktime.
anyone please help me figure out what other condition should i use to achieve this?

**Models**

*User.php*

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_members')->withTimestamps();
}
```

*Task.php*

```
public function worktimes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Worktime::class, 'task_id');
}
```

*Worktime.php*

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
} 

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'task_members', 'task_id', 'user_id', 'task_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$query` in the closure is still an instance of QueryBuilder so you can eager load with it too

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.contract_type')
            ->with([
                'tasks' => function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                    $query->with([
                        'worktimes' => function ($subQuery) {
                            $subQuery->withCount(
                                [
                                    'tags as late_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 1);
                                    },
                                    'tags as early_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 2);
                                    },
                                    'tags as others_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 3);
                                    }
                                ]
                            );
                        }
                    ])
                        ->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])
                        ->select('tasks.id', 'tasks.date');
                }
            ])
            ->get();
```

This way, the worktimes and aggregate counts are grouped per task and the tasks are group per user

### Edit 1

You could lazy load the worktimes for each users after you must have retrieved them first. This however isn't very performant especially if there are many users

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.contract_type')
    ->with([
        'tasks' => function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->select('tasks.id', 'tasks.date');
        }
    ])
    ->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->tasks->load([
        'worktimes' => function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->withCount([
                    'tags as late_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 1);
                    },
                    'tags as early_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 2);
                    },
                    'tags as others_tag_count' => function ($subQuery) {
                        $subQuery->where('tags.id', 3);
                    }
                ]);
        }
    ]);
}
```

### Edit 2

You already have a users (`belongsToMany`) relationship on the Worktime model. Defining an inverse of that relationship on the User model will work best in this situation.

```
//User.php

public function worktimes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Worktimes::class, 'task_members', 'user_id', 'task_id', 'user_id');
}

//YourController.php
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.contract_type')
    ->with(
        [
            'tasks' => function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                $query->whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->select('tasks.id', 'tasks.date');
            },
            'worktimes' => function ($query) {
                $query->withCount([
                    'tags as late_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 1);
                    },
                    'tags as early_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 2);
                    },
                    'tags as others_tag_count' => function ($subsubQuery) {
                        $subsubQuery->where('tags.id', 3);
                    }
                ]);
            }
        ]
    )
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, worktimes are grouped per task, but with other users worktime too. i want to limit the other users worktimes from task => worktime relationship

Comment: If that's the case, then you can break the statements. Since you need a way to access the `user_id`, you need to get the users first, then lazy load the worktimes for each of the users. Not elegant especially if there are many users but still works!  The best solution will be to define a direct relationship between users and worktimes. You already have a  users (`belongsToMany` )relationship on the worktimes model, you just have to define the inverse. Check the edit

Comment: I'm not into the #edit1 solution, as this cause n+1 issue. I'm currently fetching all the worktimes per task and later filter based on user id, but this can be a performance issue if there are many worktimes registered per task. Edit2 seems good to me, I'll try and accept the answer if it works (i think it'll). Thanks for your time.